# Redirect 301 an address with a / in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect an address with a / :

```
mywebsite.com/img-41/
```

to another without the /:

```
mywebsite.com/img-41
```

Of course the 41 is a variable.
I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But it doesn't work :(

Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance, lucas.

EDIT:
    SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
    SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Activation du module de réécriture d'URL :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1&auteur=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
SetEnv SESSION_USE_TRANS_SID 0
```

This is the entire .htaccess.

When I say that it doesn't work, I mean that when I go to my address with the slash, the navigator stays in this address, it doesn't go to the address without the slash :(

Comment: Provide your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it take you to a wrong place? Do  you get an error? Are you getting re-directed *back* to the one with a trailing slash?

Comment: When I say that it doesn't work, I mean that when I go to my address with the slash, the navigator stays in this address, it doesn't go to the address without the slash :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a rewrite base like this

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]+)/$ img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteBase has to be set after your "RewriteEngine On" statement

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule only redirects requests that start with `img`

Try adding a `/` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I replied before your edit,
You have already performed an internal redirect with an L flag before this line

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Activation du module de réécriture d'URL :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1&auteur=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1 [L]


Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
SetEnv SESSION_USE_TRANS_SID 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Order matters when it comes to rules, you have rules that map the pattern you're trying to match **before** the rule that does the redirect. Therefore, the redirect never happens, the URI has already been changed!

```
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1&auteur=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Here, the 2nd rule:

```
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]
```

has the exact same pattern as your last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Thus, the first rule matches it and the last rule **will never get applied**. You **always** want your redirects first:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Activation du module de réécriture d'URL :
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ /img-$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$
Rewriterule ^(.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img-([0-9]*)/$ img.php?&numlsv=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1&auteur=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^home-([0-9]*)$ index.php?&numpage=$1 [L]
```